# spring framework nesting java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, spring, maven

I want to run my first web application and I am getting this error

I have searched the web but I cant figure out what the problem is.
I have trying googling what nesting is but I could not understand what it is talking about

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/todo-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/todo-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
```

web.xml

The path to the todo-servlet is configured here.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/todo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring-mvc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have created todo-servlet.xml in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/todo-servlet.xml
but I am still getting file not found exception

Comment: did you try to rebuild the project? `mwn clean build`

Comment: I have done that but it did not work.

Comment: Your package structure is wrong. webapp/WEB-INF has to be in project directory. Can you share your package structure?